# symfony cannot find my model (Doctrine)

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I get this error when I try to use a model:
fatal error: Call to a member function getSubMenu() on a non-object in /workcedric2/bambinbazar/apps/frontend/modules/categories/actions/components.class.php on line 25

I tried clearing the cache with symfony cc and rebuilding the model... no go.

The component:

```
  public function executeSubmenu(sfWebRequest $request)
  { 
   $currentCatId = $this->getVar('currentCatId');
   $currentId = $this->getVar('currentId');
   $this->subCategories = $this->bambinbazar_category->getSubMenu($currentCatId);
}
```

The model in file BambinbazarCategory.class.php:

```
  public function getSubMenu($currentCatId)
  {
    $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('BambinbazarCategory')->createQuery('tree')
    ->where('tree.parent_id = ?', $currentCatId )
    ->addOrderBy('tree.parent_id ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('tree.lft ASC')
    ->execute();
   return $q;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently your `$this->bambinbazar_category` is null or not an object.

`executeSubmenu` doesn't set that variable, probably it is set somewhere outside, so check the code that sets it and make sure that it's not null.

Or you can just add a check before you try to call `getSubMenu`

```
if (is_object($this->bambinbazar_category)) {
     $this->subCategories = $this->bambinbazar_category->getSubMenu($currentCatId);
} else {
    $this->subcategories = array();
}
```